# Is it possible to refresh an OAuth2 token asynchronously without triggering a popup blocker?

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-signin, hello.js

I'm using [hello.js](https://github.com/MrSwitch/hello.js) to implement OAuth 2 based (google sign in) authentication for a single page web application. If the user has not allowed the site in their popup blocker then calls to refresh the token will be stopped if they were triggered by an asynchronous or non-user-initiated action.

So a user clicking a delete button that checks & refreshes the token before making a delete request will work fine. However, a background polling request to check for updated data will trigger the popup blocker if it needs to refresh the token.

To check and refresh tokens when necessary I'm wrapping all authenticated request in this hello.js login method as described in the refresh section of the docs.

```
google.login({force: false}).then(function() {
    google.api('me').then(fireRequest);
});
```

Is this issue a limitation of the library, my implementation or OAuth2 flows in general? How do other sites refresh OAuth tokens during actions that aren't synchronous user initiated events?